# Jpeg image from Android camera cannot be loaded as Qt Pixmap

Tags: android, qt, android-camera2

In my android application, I used `ImageReader` surface to capture the image from the camera and dump it into a file. Here is the relevant code:

```
void saveImage(Image img) {
   Bytebuffer buf = img.GetPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
   buf.rewind();
   byte[] data = new byte[buf.remaining()];
   buf.get(data);
   saveToFile(data);
}
```

The generated file, when viewed through `avplay,` seems to display the image just fine. However, when I load the same content using Qt's `QPixmap::loadFromData` on Ubuntu, the method fails. The errors I get are:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOI markers
```

I am wondering if anyone has any insight on how to overcome this problem. Not sure if it is a problem with Android `MediaCodec` class or the jpeg library Qt internally uses has a bug. Regards.

Comment: Why would GetPlanes()[0] be a jpg file? Use usual image viewers on your device and pc to tell you if it is indead a jpg. Is it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. When you initialize MediaCodec instance, you give it the format to output. Besides, I have also verified that the header in the binary data is valid jpeg header.

Comment: I asked you to use some common jpg viewers. What do they say?

Comment: I already mentioned that I have used avplay to verify that it is jpeg. ffmpeg also gives me proper jpeg details.